# Spring tests failing only in my system

Tags: java, spring, maven, intellij-idea

I have a JDK 1.8 project with a maven dependency to a local jar in my maven repo.

I'm able to build the project using Intellij, with the errors that a symbol cannot be found (the symbol is a class importing packages from the local jar)

I can successfully build the project using 'mvn package'.

I've spent so much time looking for solutions, things I've already done:

- Invalidated cache
- I have uninstall and install back intelliJ
- `mvn clean install -U`
- `mvn dependency:resolve`
- `mvn clean install` the local jar dependecy
- Marked to 'autoload snapshots' in Intellij's maven configuration
- Reimported maven in Intellij
- Syncronized

Still there are JUnit tests failing only into my system. Assertion errors which does not make sense.

Any ideas?

Comment: Assertion errors aren't compilation errors. Assertion error indicate a wrong test or expecting the wrong things. So fix your tests or your code. It has nothing to do with the absence of a dependency (as that wouldn't even compile your code).

Comment: Welcome to SO. I believe that the errors that you get from your tests make sense. Please try to explain your problem more specifically. Send stack trace from your tests. BTW you said that the tests fail on your system. Does it mean that they succeed on other one? In this case examine the differences.

Comment: Hi Thank you for your responses. They are failing on my system but no on others. All are assertion errors and passing fine in different systems. I will try to post some stacktrace later on.  would it be possible something to be wrong with the datasets xml files that are being used for the tests?

Comment: Without the source code of your tests and the setup it's impossible to say. Try to add some logging in your tests to see whats happening. Alternatively you can also debug your tests (just add breakpoints and run your unit test in debug mode).